# C-Linux-Any way to pass command "history" to Linux shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm writing a C program to run in Linux system.
The program will pass some Linux commands to shell and receive the result  with txt files.

```
system("last >> last.txt");
system("ls -s >>ls.txt");
```

But I failed with "history" as someone told me that this is not a command but a buildin.

So is there any way I can pass "history" as other ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might also be able to actually invoke the built-in command by using the shell:

```
system("bash -e \"history >> history.txt\"");
```

Change `"bash"` to the preferred shell.

Comment: Never mind.  I had `HISTFILE=/dev/null` set due to which it wouldn't :) +1

Answer (score 1):

"history" is equivalent to "cat ~/.bash_history", so an aternative is to use:

```
system("cat ~/.bash_history");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to add time stamp is this format of output?

Comment: @JiayiGuo It just prints what you record in the .bash_history file. If you want time stamps in the output, a variable named HISTTIMEFORMAT should be set ahead. Only after the HISTTIMEFORMAT is set, the newly recorded commands could have time stamp attached.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shell used you can look at the history file.

For example: ~/.bash_history or ~/.zsh_history.